# Create Android library

Tags: android

I've written a library (game engine) and would like to use it for my apps and games that I'll be creating.

I see there are two ways to add libraries to your code:

1. Export to jar and add that to build path
2. Have it as a project file its self, and simply add project to build    path.

I've tried the second method, yet I get a:

> Unable to instantiate activity error

**Stack trace:**

> [2012-07-15 21:06:08 - ScienceProject] ------------------------------
>   [2012-07-15 21:06:08 - ScienceProject] Android Launch! [2012-07-15
>   21:06:08 - ScienceProject] adb is running normally. [2012-07-15
>   21:06:08 - ScienceProject] Performing
>   com.webstorms.scienceproject.ScienceProjectActivity activity launch
>   [2012-07-15 21:06:08 - ScienceProject] Automatic Target Mode: using
>   existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'HVGA'
>   [2012-07-15 21:06:09 - ScienceProject] Application already deployed.
>   No need to reinstall. [2012-07-15 21:06:09 - ScienceProject] Project
>   dependency found, installing: WSGameEngine [2012-07-15 21:06:10 -
>   WSGameEngine] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
>   [2012-07-15 21:06:10 - ScienceProject] Starting activity
>   com.webstorms.scienceproject.ScienceProjectActivity on device
>   emulator-5554 [2012-07-15 21:06:12 - ScienceProject] ActivityManager:
>   Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
>   cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
>   cmp=com.webstorms.scienceproject/.ScienceProjectActivity }

Comment: Could please post your log cat and the exception stack trace? I assume you are trying to start an Activity from your library project. If that's the case, did you add that Activity to your app project's manifest file?

Comment: Added stack trace, Must I add the activity of the library into the manifest?

Comment: Yes unfortunately that is currently a shortcoming of Android library projects. Everything is available in your app project except for the library project's manifest file. This may seem like a stupid bug but it can also seen as a feature, because it gives you control over what library features and activities to use in your app.

Comment: What is the type of your game engine project exactly, Android Library Project or regular Java Project?